# Beginner to Angular Services/ In need of assistance

Tags: angularjs, angular, service

I am having troubles with using a service instead of duplicating code. How would I put this into a service and use it in the component? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public navigateLink(myRecords) {
this.myLink = this.myData.myLinks.myLink;
this.myData.access?
this.openMyModal() :
(myRecords.eligibility?
    this.myService.myStatus(myRecords, this.myData, this.csrfToken) :
    this.myModal2.openModal()
);
this.window.getWindow().location.href = this.myLink;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use the angular cli to generate a service. Run

```
ng generate service path/to/your/service/from/src/cool-name
```

This will create a service named CoolNameService

In here it defaults to provided in root, which is probably what you want since this code looks like it could be a singleton. Creat a method that holds this logic. Each of the values that have ‘this.’ will either need to be passed in as parameters or deared as service properties at the top of the service class.

You the pass this service into your components constructor and Angular use dependency injection to instant oats your service in the component.

```
constructor(private service: CoolNameService) { }
```